# EinsteinPy--how does one plot the output of a single element of a tensor with respect to multiple coordinates?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, computational-physics, software

I would like to plot a component of the Einstein tensor from a metric computed in [EinsteinPy](https://einsteinpy.org/). In order to get this metric, I used `einst=EinsteinTensor.from_metric()` and then `einst.tensor()[i][j]`, where i and j are the indices of the component I want to plot. When I print the value of this object, I get an equation, but I can't seem to plot it. Is there any way to plot this object with respect to a set of coordinates (i.e. a 3d surface plot with respect to x and t)?

I figured that because Einsteinpy makes use of scipy, I could simply use the scipy plot3d feature with respect to some coordinates. However, running the code prints the error

`TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: AttributeError: 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute 'extract_multiplicatively'`
when I run the line
`plot3d(einst[i][j], (syms[1],-5,5), (syms[0],-5,5), show=True)`

(I cut down the error message to hide my file directory and remove some of the line numbers and such)

If it helps, printing the type of the object einst.tensor()[i][j] gives class `'sympy.core.add.Add'`.

Of note is that the I can successfully perform operations such as `sympy.Mul(einst[i][j],2)`, so I'm unsure why plotting this function with sympy isn't working.

Comment: This seems like a question for the einsteinpy devs (e.g., their [Github issues](https://github.com/einsteinpy/einsteinpy/issues); their [homepage](https://einsteinpy.org/) also has a "Community" link to a riot.im webpage that I'm unfamiliar with, but could also be used).

Comment: From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)… “If your question is about implementing computational code - in particular, if it's about writing, compiling, debugging or optimizing code, or about a specific language or library - then it is off topic.”

Comment: @Kyle Kanos Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try that!